# Canvas Publish/Subscribe and Javascript

Tags: canvas

I am trying to hack together a Canvas App so I can understand the Publish/Subscribe Model. I have a VF page in a dev org calling a URL in a SFDC Prod Org (so it has HTPPS) that just displays another VF page. 
I can get the basic samples in the docs to work (re-size/alert for Chatter users) but I cannot for the life of me get the VF page to publish, and my other page to subscribe...I just get an error from the CanvasApp Page in the console saying

> Uncaught precondition fail

EDIT:
The Canvas docs suggest I need include a reference to Controller.js - but the links they provide go nowhere - anyone know if this is still true, and if so, where I can find it?

VF Page in Org Using Canvas App:

```
<apex:page >
<script type="text/javascript" src="/canvas/sdk/js/29.0/canvas-all.js"/>

<apex:canvasApp applicationName="pnctest1" height="800px" parameters="{p1:'value1',p2:'value2',p3:'value3'}"/>

 <script>
         Sfdc.canvas (function () { 

         Sfdc.canvas.client.publish(
         {name: 'pnc.testAction', payload: {}
         }); 
         });

   </script>
</apex:page>
```

VF Page in Org Hosting Canvas App:

```
<apex:page controller="oAuthSetupforZDM" cache="FALSE">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://na15.salesforce.com/canvas/sdk/js/29.0/canvas-all.js"/>

 <script>
 var sJson = [Working JSON Request];
 var sr = JSON.parse(sJson);
 Sfdc.canvas (function () {
            Sfdc.canvas.client.resize(sr.client, {height : "225px"});

            Sfdc.canvas.client.subscribe({name : 'pnc.testAction', 
                                  onData : function (e) {
                                      }
                                  });
 });           
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did get this to work eventually....looks like the link to Controller.Js in the docs is broken - they sent me [this link](https://org62.my.salesforce.com/canvas/sdk/js/30.0/controller.js) that does work

I added that js code into my calling VF page, and was then able to click a link on my originating VF page to trigger an event in the Canvas App to post back to Chatter in my Org the value from my event...

```
<apex:page >

<script type="text/javascript" src="/canvas/sdk/js/29.0/canvas-all.js"/>
<script>
(function(global) {
  var module = function() {

    function subscribe(event) {
      Sfdc.canvas.parent.subscribe(event)
    }

    function unsubscribe(event) {
      Sfdc.canvas.parent.unsubscribe(event)
    }

    function publish(event) {
      Sfdc.canvas.parent.publish(event)
    }

    function resize(size, target) {
      Sfdc.canvas.parent.resize(size, target)
    }
    return{subscribe:subscribe, unsubscribe:unsubscribe, publish:publish, resize:resize}
  }();

  global.Sfdc = global.Sfdc || {};
  global.Sfdc.canvas = global.Sfdc.canvas || {};
  global.Sfdc.canvas.controller = module
})(this);
</script>

<apex:canvasApp applicationName="pnctest1" height="800px" parameters="{p1:'value1',p2:'value2',p3:'value3'}"/>

<script>

        function testpayload (msg) { 

         Sfdc.canvas.controller.publish({
             name: 'pnc.testAction', 
             payload : {status : msg}
             }); 

         };

   </script>

<apex:form >
<apex:commandLink onclick="testpayload('Open')" value="Open" reRender="TestPanel"/><br/>
<apex:commandLink onclick="testpayload('Closed')" value="Closed" reRender="TestPanel"/>
<apex:outputPanel id="TestPanel">
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>   
</apex:page>
```

And then in my Canvas App:

```
<apex:page controller="oAuthSetupforZDM" cache="FALSE">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://na15.salesforce.com/canvas/sdk/js/29.0/canvas-all.js"/>

 <script>
  var sJson = [SignedRequestJSON];

 var sr = JSON.parse(sJson);

Sfdc.canvas(function() {
Sfdc.canvas.client.subscribe(sr.client,
{name : 'pnc.testAction', onData : function (data) {

var url = sr.context.links.chatterFeedsUrl+"/news/"+sr.context.user.userId+"/feed-items";
var body = {body : {messageSegments : [{type: "Text", text: "We are " + data.status}]}};
Sfdc.canvas.client.ajax(url,
{client : sr.client,
method: 'POST',
contentType: "application/json",
data: JSON.stringify(body),
success : function(data) {
if (201 === data.status) {
console.log('Success');
}
}
});

</script>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

As a note here, the Sfdc.canvas.parent.* methods are not supported for client use.  Instead we expose the methods using Sfdc.canvas.controller.*

So for the code above to be supported by salesforce, you would need to:

1. Add the controller.js file as a script tag in the VF page:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/canvas/sdk/js/30.0/controller.js"/>
   ```
2. Change the method calls to use Sfdc.canvas.controller.subscribe, Sfdc.canvas.controller.publish, Sfdc.canvas.controller.unsubscribe, and Sfdc.canvas.controller.resize where appropriate